# Updating Open VPN on a Centos 7 server: is there a risk of messing things up?

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn, centos7, update

I use Open VPN on a Centos 7 server and the open-vpn package needs to be updated after a little over a year since its install.

The update can be done fairly easily (using yum) but I'm worried this might mess things up (in my server-side VPN configuration for example).

The server is currently used for important projects and even if I can afford to take a few days right now to perform some adjustments, if the VPN connection is broken I will loose the only entry point to the server (which will probably mean the server will be unavailable for work for a little time until I fix or reinstall the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating OpenVPN will require it to restart, which will drop all open connections. You can then just reconnect to the VPN. Your configurations are not changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A restart is not an issue since there is no ongoing work that requires continuous server operation right now. As long as the configuration remains the same (and it reconnects well), it's good.